# How to import data from CSV file to HTML page

Tags: html, css, csv

I am making a website of my shop items, where I need to daily update the items which includes item_name, brand_name, price, item_no., etc. Writing html codes daily is becoming very hard work for me. So, I want to make changes about the items in a CSV file, and import the data into my website. How to do that, Please help me. Thank you in advance. Here is some sample codes:

**read_data.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>Reading values from csv file</title></head>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    width: 300px;
}
img{
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div>
<img src="#" alt="item 1"><br>
Item Name:<!--CSV file data--><br>
Item Number:<!--CSV file data--><br>
Brand Name:<!--CSV file data-->
</div>
<div>
<img src="#" alt="item 2"><br>
Item Name:<!--CSV file data--><br>
Item Number:<!--CSV file data--><br>
Brand Name:<!--CSV file data-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**data.csv**

```
Item Name,Item no.,Brand
T-shirt,555,Hoffmen
Pants,556,Reliance
```

Comment: This isn't gonna happen with just css and html. Look into server-side languages such as php, ruby or python. Or something client-side with javascript.

Comment: It's simple with PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is assuming you have a way to store the data (e.g. a database). It sounds like you would benefit from a CMS (e.g. Wordpress). Anyway, this answer addresses the question of how to get the CSV data:

You can use [Papa parse](http://papaparse.com/). It would look something like this:

```
// from file upload field
var file = event.target.inputCSV.value;
var data = Papa.parse(file, {header: true, skipEmptyLines: true, delimiter: ','});
return data;
// outputs something like [{Item_Name: "T-shirt", Item_no: 555, Brand: "Hoffman"}, {Item_Name: "Pants", Item_no: 556, Brand: "Reliance"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Saptarshi, you'll probably need a database for this, where you can possibly import your CSV. This will help your handling and automize it. The solution might be based on a php/mySQL basis, for example. I'd do some research on the specialties and power of these languages first.